# Mongodb aggregate lookup by _id is not working

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, lookup

MongoDb Aggregate lookup is not producing result while foreignField as _id.
I have two collections say `users` and `discussions`

Sample `users` Data:

```
[{
    _id: 5f9c50dcfac1f091400225e3,
    email: 'Peter.Parker@gmail.com',
    details: { fname: 'Peter Test', lname: 'Fulton' },
},
{
    _id: 5fa432bfb91fab7db60c70eb,
    email: 'Spidy@xxx.com',
    details: { fname: 'Frodo', lname: 'Baggins' },
},
{
    _id: 5fa8ec7d3ce22610e5d15190,
    email: 'tommy@xxx.com',
    details: { fname: 'Tommy', lname: 'test' },
},
{
    _id: 5fc38bb0b3683651be970180,
    email: 'jerry@xxx.io',
},
{
    _id: 5fd2340cc443d155ab38383b,
    email: 'Dexter@xxx.io',
    details: { fname: 'Dexter', lname: 'Lab' },
}]
```

Sample `discussions` data:

```
 {_id: ObjectId("5fb2abd6b14fa5683979df58"),
  tags: [ 'javascritp', 'css', 'html' ],
  title: 'Why is this inline-block element pushed downward?',
  post: 'Test Post',
  learnerId: ObjectId("5f9c50dcfac1f091400225e3"),
 }
```

Here '`_id`' of `users` is linked with '`learnerId`' of '`discussions`'.

My Aggregate query is like below.

```
db.users.aggregate([
            { $project: { "details.fname": 1, "details.lname":1,email:1, _id:1}},
            {$lookup: {
                from: "discussions",
                localField: "learnerId",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "discussions"
            }}
        ])
```

Here `'Peter Test'` with _id `5f9c50dcfac1f091400225e3` linked with `discussions LeanerId`. But I expected discussions will populate in my result. My am seeing empty discussions array in all users collections.

```
 [{
    _id: 5f9c50dcfac1f091400225e3,
    email: 'Peter.Parker@gmail.com',
    details: { fname: 'Peter Test', lname: 'Fulton' },
    discussions: []
},
{
    _id: 5fa432bfb91fab7db60c70eb,
    email: 'Spidy@xxx.com',
    details: { fname: 'Frodo', lname: 'Baggins' },
    discussions: []
},
{
    _id: 5fa8ec7d3ce22610e5d15190,
    email: 'tommy@xxx.com',
    details: { fname: 'Tommy', lname: 'test' },
    discussions: []
},
{
    _id: 5fc38bb0b3683651be970180,
    email: 'jerry@xxx.io',
    discussions: []
},
{
    _id: 5fd2340cc443d155ab38383b,
    email: 'Dexter@xxx.io',
    details: { fname: 'Dexter', lname: 'Lab' },
    discussions: []
}]
```

Can you point out what wrong in my aggregate query here?

Comment: You have different types for ids, maybe they don't match as a result.

Comment: You have mismatched the ids.. Working mongo playground https://mongoplayground.net/p/YDSJl1VU62S

Comment: Thank you for your response. I misunderstood. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mismatched the localField and foreignField

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "details.fname": 1,
      "details.lname": 1,
      email: 1,
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "discussions",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "learnerId",
      as: "discussions"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YDSJl1VU62S)**